Unlucky seven dice game
Question - You are given a fair 6−sided die and you roll it. You can either choose to keep your roll and receive the observed value in dollars. Alternatively, you are allowed to roll again, but if the sum of your two rolls is at least 7, you pay the value equal to your first roll. If the sum of the two rolls is less than 7, you receive the second observed value in dollars. Assuming optimal play, what is your expected payout?
My solution:

I considered the expected payout of the game if we always rerolled conditioning on the number we got in the first round. Let $X_1$ be the value of the first roll and $Y$ be the payout.
$E(Y|X_1 = 1) = \frac{5}{6} * (1+2+3+4+5) - \frac{1}{6} * 1 = \frac{74}{6}$. Since $1<\frac{74}{6}$ it would be better to reroll if we got $1$ in the first round.
Similarly $E(Y|X_1 = 2) = \frac{4}{6} * (1+2+3+4) - \frac{2}{6} * 2 = \frac{36}{6} = 3$. Again since $2<3$, it would be better to reroll.
Then carrying on, $E(Y|X_1 = 3) = \frac{3}{6} * (1+2+3) - \frac{3}{6} * 3 = \frac{9}{6}$ and as $3>\frac{9}{6}$, he shouldn't reroll.
So our strategy will be to reroll only if we get 1 or 2. So our expected payout is $E(Y) = \frac{1}{6} * \frac{74}{6} + \frac{1}{6} * 6 + \frac{4}{6} * (3+4+5+6) = 271/18$

Anyone know why this answer/logic is wrong? I'm not sure of the actual answer but this got marked as incorrect

Did you think 271/18 is correct?

Should $E(Y\mid X_1=1)$ be $\frac 16*$(1+2+3+4+5) - \frac16*$1$ instead? It seems that $\frac{74}6\ge 12$ and is too good.

Your conditional expectations are incorrect.
If you roll a $1$ the first time, and choose to roll again, there is a $\frac{5}{6}$ chance you win something and $\frac{1}{6}$ chance you lose $1$. When you win something, you win $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ with equal probability, so the expectation is $3$. Therefore, the expected winning for the second roll should be
$$\frac{5}{6} (3) + \frac{1}{6} (-1) = \color{red}{\frac{7}{3}}$$
Obviously $\frac{7}{3} > 1$, so it is advantageous to reroll.
If $2$ is rolled the first time, the second roll has an expected value of
$$\frac{2}{3} \left( \frac{5}{2} \right) + \frac{1}{3} (-2) = 1$$
where $\frac{5}{2}$ is the average of the winning values of $1, 2, 3, 4$. Since $1 < 2$, it is not advantageous to roll again.
We can actually stop here, because we know that the expected value of the second roll when the first roll is higher will be lower: it is not advantageous to reroll unless the first roll is $1$.
So, the value of the game is
$$\frac{1}{6} \left( \frac{7}{3} \right) + \frac{5}{6} (4) = \boxed{\frac{67}{18}}$$
where $4$ is the average of $2, 3, 4, 5, 6$, the first roll values where you do not choose to reroll.



$E(Y|X_1 = 1) = \frac{5}{6} * (1+2+3+4+5) - \frac{1}{6} * 1$


That $\frac{5}{6}$ should be $\frac{1}{6}$.
You did the same mistake a few times, and also $\frac{36}{6}$ isn't $3$.
